# Laravel not flashing errors during in-built validation

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel for my PHP project. When accepting a POST request, I use the inbuilt validate feature. This is supposed to pass errors if this is not fulfilled with similar function to `Session::flash`. Despite this, when I call `$errors` this does not return any errors.

Comment: How are you calling `$errors`? It isn't a normal session variable but a class. `$errors->any()` will return `true` or `false`, if it returns `true` you can then use `$errors->all()` to retrieve them.

Comment: How are you using the validation feature and where are you trying to access `$errors` ?

Comment: RMcLeod this works can you write this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$errors` is made available to you it isn't just an array of errors it is actually an instance of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag`, with a few methods for checking to see if errors exist `$errors->any()`, Accessing specific errors `$errors->first('name')`, or all errors `$errors->all()` have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#working-with-error-messages) for more details on how to interact with this object.